# not able to display record count in data table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have used jquery data table plug in for showing my data.
I want to show the record count at the bottom of my data table.
please anyone help me how to do it?

```
 $('.data-table').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "sDom": '<"dt_head"fp>t<"F"l>'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sDom parameter there is an option 'i' for showing record count.suppose if you want to show record count in footer add like below

```
  "sDom": '<"dt_head"fp>t<"F"il>'
```

Answer (score 3):

Include this option at the time of initializing your datatable

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "bInfo": true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have search it on [Datatable.net](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2278/how-to-get-number-of-rows/p1) itself. You can easily get many references from there.

The one i found to work is

```
oTable.fnGetData().length
```

Also check their [API documentation](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnGetHiddenNodes) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You need not add any defaults to jquery datatable declaration. By default it will display summary, search, sort and so on.

Consider table id is kalyan

then just use :

```
kalyan = $('#kalyan').datatable();
```

If you want to use a custom one on your own then  :

```
kalyan.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal() //should do it.

kalyan.fnSettings().fnRecordsDisplay() //will give you the number after filtering has occurred.
```

Cheers